# Loopback validation not working in update query?

Tags: node.js, validation, backend, loopbackjs

Validation working for create query. But the same validation not working fot updateAll query in loopback v2.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. your question does not provide enough information for us to help you. Please take the tour : https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

It's true and resonable. The validation requires to load a model from database. The `updateAll` query can affect many instances (even all data in your table). If to add validation for this functionality, it can be big performance issue.